# pyspark df.select(*) is disordered after df.sort()

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

This is my original pyspark dataframe.

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   1|   2|
|   1|   2|   2|
|   1|   3|   2|
|   1|   2|   1|
|   2|   1|   2|
|   2|   3|   2|
|   2|   2|   1|
|   3|   1|   2|
|   3|   3|   2|
|   3|   2|   1|
+----+----+----+
```

On sorting df

```
df = df.sort('col2')
test = df.select('col1','col2','col3')
test.show()
```

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   3|   1|   2|
|   2|   1|   2|
|   1|   1|   2|
|   1|   2|   1|
|   3|   2|   1|
|   1|   2|   2|
|   2|   2|   1|
|   1|   3|   2|
|   3|   3|   2|
|   2|   3|   2|
+----+----+----+
```

```
df.show()
```

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   2|   1|   2|
|   3|   1|   2|
|   1|   1|   2|
|   1|   2|   2|
|   3|   2|   1|
|   1|   2|   1|
|   2|   2|   1|
|   3|   3|   2|
|   2|   3|   2|
|   1|   3|   2|
+----+----+----+
```

We can see that the row order of the test is different from df, I don't know what happened, can someone help me understand?

Comment: not reproducible. Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: it is reproducible to me, the dataframe is created like below:
'''
data = [(1,1,2),
    (1,2,2),
    (1,3,2),   
    (1,2,1),
    (2,1,2),
    (2,3,2),
    (2,2,1),
    (3,1,2),
    (3,3,2),
    (3,2,1)]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("col1", IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("col2", IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("col3", IntegerType(),True)])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
'''

Comment: what I have done is spark=SparkSession.builder.master('local[8]').appName("SparkByExample.com").getOrCreate(), afte I changed 8 to 1, they are the same. but don't know the reason